# What affects the 'Current Sprint' in agile view in visual studio online?

Tags: azure-devops

I have this sprint scheme, but still today at 7/10/2017 sprint 3 shows up as the current sprint. Should be Sprint 4. 
How is the current sprint determined, besides on the dates? I can't get this clear!

[image: sprint scheme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on the date.

Refer to these steps to check whether the Sprint 4 has already been added to current team:

1. Go to team project admin overview page (https://[account].visualstudio.com/[teamproject]/_admin).
2. Click a team.
3. Click Work tab > Iterations.
4. Check Iteration list and add Sprint 4 to Iteration list.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot. 
Step 3 wasn't totally clear to me, maybe a better description would be: 
Click 'Work' tab, then link 'Iterations'